# How to add element to Java Generic Wildcard List

Tags: java, android, generics, sharedpreferences, wildcard

How could I add string and int value to a HashMap same time ?

```
HashMap<String,?> map =new HashMap<>();
map.put("sss", "str");
map.put("sss", 1);
```

How Android `SharedPreferences.getAll()` method did this?

**Error message**

```
Found 'java.lang.String', required: '?'
```

Comment: Why do you think you need such functionality?

Comment: You can't add things to a map with an upper-bounded wildcard. It could be a `HashMap<String, Long>`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I'm pointing out why you *can't* add it to a `Map<String, ?>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah. Ok. Misunderstood. I first read your last sentence as a recommendation what OP should do instead.

Comment: Did you try setting to Object type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add anything (other than literal `null`) to a `Map<String, ?>`, because it could be the wrong type. For example:

```
Map<String, Long> longMap = ...;
Map<String, ?> wildcardMap = longMap;
wildcardMap.put("", "");  // Compiler error!

// but if it did work, the following would be a runtime error:
Long value = longMap.values().iterator().next();
```

Remember that `?` is a shorthand for `? extends Object`; and the acronym [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) tells you that something which `extends` is a *producer*, not a *consumer*. So, you can't invoke a *consumer* method on an instance of it (unless you pass `null`).

If you want to put heterogeneous values into the map, the value type has to be a common superclass of the types.

```
Map<String, Object> mapForBoth = ...
mapForBoth.put("key1", "string");
mapForBoth.put("key2", 1);
```

(Actually, `Serializable` is a more specific common superclass of `String` and `Integer`; it's up to you as to whether that's a better value type)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 HashMap<String,Object> map =new HashMap<>();
 map.put("sss", "str");
 map.put("sss", 1);
```